# What citations of the Fair Labor Standards Act Federal Law made 4 million employees eligible for overtime?

Tags: united-states, labor-law

I was reading a Pittsburgh Post Gazette article entitled ["Time Change"](http://www.post-gazette.com/business/career-workplace/2016/11/07/WorkZone-Federal-change-to-make-4-million-more-employees-eligible-for-overtime/stories/201611060068) in the "Businesses and Jobs" section of the newspaper from Sunday November 6, 2016.

The article states that a federal law has been modified called the "Fair Labor Standards Act" by the U.S. Department of Labor that requires non-profits organizations to:

1. More than double the salary threshold at which employees are exempt from overtime protections.

   1. Under the existing rule from 2004, employers must pay overtime to
      full-time employees who earn $23,660 or less annually if they work
      more than 40 hours a week.
2. Any non-profit with annual gross revenues over $500,000 is subject to the rules and the DOL plans to raise the overtime threshold every three years beginning in 2020.
3. Under the revised regulation, the salary level under which employees qualify for overtime pay will jump to $47,476 a year.

So which citations of that law have been modified, added or removed to specify this in [legal citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/15324/9716)?

Comment: Here's a podcast where a woman that is mentioned in the article discusses the modification to the Fair Labor Standards Act: http://www.startupburgh.com/sub/11

Comment: Well that must be really buried deep then...

Comment: Is this it? http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=(title:29%20section:203%20edition:prelim)%20OR%20(granuleid:USC-prelim-title29-section203)&f=treesort&edition=prelim&num=0&jumpTo=true#amendment-note  If so how do I read that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this refers to regulatory changes that were published in the [*Federal Register* of May 23, 2016, pages 32391-32552](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2016-05-23/pdf/2016-11754.pdf), revising 29 CFR Part 541 (i.e. the Code of Federal Regulations, Title 29, Part 541).  Most of the publication discusses the rationale and effects of the rule change.  The actual changes to the text of the regulations begin on page 32549.

Comment: I agree, the change was in the language of the regulation, not the statute itself.